# getting node value of a DOM tree but not the scripts

Tags: java, dom

in the anyway to get nodes value of a `DOM's` node while its not scripts? i mean because there could be tens of scripts codes in a page source , when we traversing the DOM tree of the corresponding page, And when we use the method `node.getNodeValue()` it will retrieve the content of node even if its scripts whic is none of my concern. i just would like to get the content of the node if its an actual text that appears in the page.

```
 public void traverse( Node rootNode) 
        {


Stack stack = new Stack();
Node node=rootNode.getFirstChild();

while (node!=null) {


           System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());



        if ( node.hasChildNodes()) {

    if (node.getNextSibling()!=null)
    stack.push( node.getNextSibling() );
    node = node.getFirstChild();

}

else {

    node = node.getNextSibling();

    if (node==null && !stack.isEmpty())
    {
        node=(Node) stack.pop();

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using XPath or [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/) or [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for dealing with your HTML? You'll probably write a lot less code (and less bugs) with those techniques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the answer by myself!

```
    if(!"script".equals(node.getNodeName()))
                    System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
```